# How to set a request timeout in http:inbound-endpoint in mule XML configuration file?

Tags: java, http, mule, endpoint

I create a flow with an inbound HTTP endpoint according to the document([click here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/HTTP+Transport+Reference)):

```
<flow name="testComponent">
    <http:inbound-endpoint name="clientEndpoint" address="http://localhost:8080/foo"/>
    <echo-component/>
</flow>
```

And how to  set a request timeout in http:inbound-endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You actually set the **responseTimeout** attribute.

Comment: Do you mean to  set an attribute `responseTimeout` in `http:inbound-endpoint` ?